# Duplicating of QgsLayoutItemGroup with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, pyqgis-3, duplication

I want to programmatically add a header and a footer as I use atlas with multipages for one feature but I can't predict the number of pages for the table depending on the feature.

In order to add the header and footer, I want to copy a [`QgsLayoutItemGroup`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.12/core/QgsLayoutItemGroup.html?#module-QgsLayoutItemGroup) and all the associated items to position them on other pages. I can easily through the GUI, copy and paste the `QgsLayoutItemGroup` but I don't see how I can do it with [PyQGIS](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.12/) and make change automatically. Pointers welcome!

I've changed the original function code to only deal with group to remove references between objects and rename them as the answer provided was keeping some unwanted references between group. It's clearly not enough generic but it fits my use case: a group with items but no other group within it.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QUuid
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.core import QgsReadWriteContext

def duplicate_item_group(item, layout, position=None):
    doc = QDomDocument()
    element = doc.createElement('Copied items')
    context = QgsReadWriteContext()
    
    group_uuid = QUuid.createUuid().toString()
    item.writeXml(element, doc, context)
    if type(item) == QgsLayoutItemGroup:
        print(len(item.items()))
        for subitem in item.items():
            subitem.writeXml(element, doc, context)
    doc.appendChild(element)
    layout_items = doc.elementsByTagName('LayoutItem')
    uuids = []
    for i in range(layout_items.count()):
        item_node = layout_items.at(i + 1)
        if item_node.isElement():
            item_node.toElement().removeAttribute('uuid')
            uuid = QUuid.createUuid().toString()
            uuids.append(uuid)
            item_node.toElement().setAttribute('groupUuid', group_uuid)
            item_node.toElement().setAttribute('templateUuid', uuid)

    group_elements = doc.elementsByTagName('ComposerItemGroupElement')
    for i in range(group_elements.count()):
        item_node = group_elements.at(i)
        if item_node.isElement():
            item_node.toElement().setAttribute('uuid', uuids[i])
    # print(doc.toString()) # To debug the XML content
    if position is None:
        return layout.addItemsFromXml(element, doc, context)
    else:
        return layout.addItemsFromXml(element, doc, context, QPoint(*position))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copy/paste mechanism for layout items is implemented in the [`QgsLayoutView`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/gui/QgsLayoutView.html) class ([`copyItems`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f48e1c89a34579c8f7d0a1ba8af40865cb73b7a1/src/gui/layout/qgslayoutview.cpp#L315), [`pasteItems`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f48e1c89a34579c8f7d0a1ba8af40865cb73b7a1/src/gui/layout/qgslayoutview.cpp#L394)).

I'm not sure if there's a way to use these functions without opening and accessing the Layout window, but we can write a Python function that works directly with the layout object:

```py
def duplicate_item(item, layout, position=None):
    doc = QDomDocument('Clipboard')
    element = doc.createElement('Copied items')
    context = QgsReadWriteContext()
    
    item.writeXml(element, doc, context)
    if type(item) == QgsLayoutItemGroup:
        for subitem in item.items():
            subitem.writeXml(element, doc, context)
    doc.appendChild(element)
    layout_items = doc.elementsByTagName('LayoutItem')
    for i in range(layout_items.count()):
        item_node = layout_items.at(i)
        if item_node.isElement():
            item_node.toElement().removeAttribute('uuid')
            item_node.toElement().removeAttribute('groupUuid')
    
    if position is None:
        return layout.addItemsFromXml(element, doc, context)
    else:
        return layout.addItemsFromXml(element, doc, context, QPoint(*position))
```

For instance, if you want to copy the first group on the first layout to a new location, you can call the code as follows from the Python console in QGIS:

```py
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0]
group = [item for item in layout.items() if type(item)==QgsLayoutItemGroup][0]
duplicate_item(group, layout, [50, 80])
```

Comment: Tried again and buggy not in the sense it does not work at all but because execute multiple times `duplicate_item(group, layout, [50, 80])` in the PyQGIS console, then try to move and select each group in the GUI to see they are grouped with the others. Conclusion: the code does not copy the group correctly and some reference exists between groups...

Comment: @ThomasG77: You're right, one of the resulting groups contains references to the elements in the other group. I'll take a look at how to fix this later today

Comment: @ThomasG77: Actually, it seems like the same thing happens when I copy and paste a group using the GUI (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V). Could you verify whether this is also the case for you? Also, could you edit your question to include an example of the types of objects you have in your group?

Comment: Same issue using GUI. You can see in my edit how I've solved the issue reusing your code without the side effect we've seen. If you find a better/more generic solution, feedback welcome!

Comment: @ThomasG77: Your approach of removing the `groupUuid` in addition to the `uuid` is the answer. It's not necessary to manually generate new `uuid`s and `groupUuid`s, that's handled correctly when restoring the objects from the XML. I've edited my code accordingly.